# Scatter plots with Matplotlib in which points are colored based on distance among them

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I’d like to plot with matplotlib several scatter graphs in which the points automatically are colored based on distance among them.
The idea is that the routine was able to calculate the average distance from a point and all other, perform this calculation for all points and compare the average distance between the nth point and others. The point with minimum average distance should be colored with the max bright color in a color scale set by user (colormap, like for example the Reds sequential colormaps: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html) while the point with maximum average distance with the max shaded color of the color scale.
Is there already a function that perform what I asked and can be used quickly in matplotlib, or is it necessary to write a specific function that does the calculation? Can you also suggest a different calculation approach, maybe more efficient?

The code from I want to start is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
y = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
plt.scatter(x, y)

x = np.array([6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
y = np.array([1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28])
plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Well, the two series of points (blue and orange) should be colored in a specific color of the colormap choosen by user, but really I can't understand how to assign to each point a color of colormap based on reciprocal points distance, in order to see in bright color the points that are spatially more dense/closer and in shaded color the points that are spatially less dense/closer.

[image: Image example]

**Details after @user3128 answer:**

What I mean in the comment is the following. If I have the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
y = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
xy_set1 = np.column_stack([x, y])
plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, marker='s', color='darkslategray', label='set1')

x = np.linspace(1.0,15.0,num=10000)
y = 2.5*x-8
xy_set2 = np.column_stack([x, y])
plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, marker='o', color='darkslategray', label='set2')

#Calculate distances
# To install sklearn: pip install scikit-learn
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
distances_matrix = pairwise_distances(xy_set1, xy_set2)
average_distances_set1 = distances_matrix.mean(axis=1)
average_distances_set2 = distances_matrix.mean(axis=0)

#Plot points and colour by distance (use a reversed colour map)
s1 = plt.scatter(xy_set1[:, 0], xy_set1[:, 1], c=average_distances_set1, s=20, marker='s', cmap='Reds_r')
plt.colorbar(label='distance | set 1')

s2 = plt.scatter(xy_set2[:, 0], xy_set2[:, 1], c=average_distances_set2, s=20, marker='o', cmap='Reds_r')
plt.colorbar(label='distance | set 2')

plt.legend()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

I obtain the following plot, in which my goal is to see the very dense set of points (set2) with very bright color respect to the set1:

[image]

In fact, if the function in line 10 is changed to 'y=1.5*x+4' , for example, the points in set1 near x=12 are too dark, they should be light compared to the points in set2 that are very dense, signifying that only along the portion of the graph that runs along set2 the relationship between X and Y follows a trend more visible and "strong" (dark color in colormap) and thus maybe with a greater frequency of occurrence.

**This is my goal**: suppose I’ve a lot of points that represents a relationship between parameter X and parameter Y of a particular natural/physical phenomenon. Where I have some very dense 2D areas with a lot of points, the color should be bright (or dark in the chosen colormap), while where area is sparse (few points or with great distance among them) the color should be shaded (or light in the chosen colormap). In other words: where I’ve a lot of points with little distance among them it means that the physical phenomenon that I’m representing via plot (parameter Y respect to parameter X) could follow a particular math law, that is well visible by bright colored points that are distributed in a specific 2D shape in the scatter plot (for example they could follow a specific power law), while poor representative points, that are less frequent and could represent a strange and not strong relationship between Y and X in that 2D portion, should be colored with shaded color.
Basically I would like to use color scales to visualize on a 2D graph a particular trend (if any) between two parameters of a certain natural phenomenon.

Comment: This is certainly possible, but here on Stack Overflow we help debug code not write code. Many other posts on SO explain how to find the pairwise distance between points and how to color scatter plot points based on a value. You will have to write some functionality yourself, but it should be pretty simple.

Comment: Ok @jared, thanks for your hints. I will search on SO more closely, and to adapt what is useful to my goal. However from your answer it seem to me that in matplotlib there is not a built-in function about it.

Comment: Matplotlib won't find the distances for you, but once you have the distances you can just pass the average distances through the colormap to get color them accordingly. You essentially just have to generate a vector containing the average pairwise distances for each point and then Matplotlib can use that for coloring.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd guess it will just be 4 or 5 lines of code on top of what you already have (assuming you do things efficiently).

Comment: Thank so much for idea @jared, I will try to write a routine to perform the comparison of distances. Probably, if I haven't miscalculated, it requires $\frac{(n^{2}-n)}{2}$ distance calculations, with $n$ total number of points. I hope to find an efficient solution.

Comment: 1. LaTeX doesn't work on Stack Overflow since it isn't a math site. 2. Do you have a lot of points? If not, don't worry about a perfectly-optimized distance calculation method. You can just do this using Numpy broadcasting and vectorized operations.

Comment: 1. It's a pity that SO does not implement Latex, no big deal however. 
2. My points are actually rainfall height values in mm at various time instants (minutes), measured by a rain gauging station, and considering all rain events (each of which has a certain duration) in a certain historical period, which can be several years long. Furthermore, I would like to create a graph showing the data from different rain gauges in a certain geographical area.

Comment: In practice I think the points could be in the order of a million (but this is a very rough estimate because I have yet to find a way to retrieve rainfall data efficiently from various weather station sites). The final graph will be a set of points showing me the typical rainfall height trend in a certain geographical area with the help of colours, in the manner discussed so far and for which I have asked for help.

Comment: So why do you need the distance between points?

Comment: @jared because I think that only distance among all points can give me a math parameter to assign a color to each point: for example, if I have in a 2D plot 1000 points, and only 10 point are very far from a specific area of the graph where I find 990 points, I want that the algorithm assigns bright color to the most dense points area (990 points) and shaded color to the few 10 points. But if you can suggest me other approach more strong I will be very happy.

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere since yesterday?

Comment: Nope, the festive days have passed too quickly. But I've in mind the pseudocode, and user3128 gave me the recipe to assign color. I hope to write something working next weekend.

Comment: I see you've updated the post. I no longer understand what you are looking for. I thought you had a scattering of points and wanted to consider all the points with respect to each other and color them based on their average proximity to all other points.

Comment: It seems the description of what you want is still unclear.  Based on what user3128 elaborated, line density of points in set2 (denser set) is all the same along the axis.  From what you mentioned so far, what I guess is that all the points from set2 needs to have same color but brighter than set1.  But all of this is just guessing as what you want is unclear from the post..

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. Exactly: the color of each point should depend on its distance from all others, regardless of whether I have multiple sets (set1, set2, ...). In my second post I reported @user3128's code, where set2 has many points (10000) and I expect the color of the points of set2 close to the coordinate (x=8, y=10) to be much more pronounced and darker than the color of the point of set1 at the similar coordinate ((x=10, y=10) for example).

Comment: This because points near set2 (near coordinate (x=8, y=10)) are more and more dense than points near set1 (near coordinate (x=10, y=10) for example). In other words: set1 and set2 should not be treated separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Computing the mean distance is trivial, no need for external libraries but Numpy.

CAVEAT if you want to operate on millions of points, as you state in comments, your distance matrices will have a no. of entries > 10<sup>12</sup> and you'll need a computer with a few Tera bytes of memory — or you'll devise a slower but less memory hungry algorithm.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20231228) ;  npt = 300
x, y = np.random.rand(npt), np.random.rand(npt)

# mean distance ####################################################
m_d = np.sum(np.sqrt((x-x[:,None])**2+(y-y[:,None])**2), axis=0)/npt
####################################################################

plt.scatter(x, y, c=m_d, cmap='Reds_r', ec='k', lw=0.3)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

---

Just to show how it works

```
In [24]: x = np.arange(6)

In [25]: x-x[:,None]
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0]])

In [26]: (x-x[:,None])**2
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25],
       [ 1,  0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
       [ 4,  1,  0,  1,  4,  9],
       [ 9,  4,  1,  0,  1,  4],
       [16,  9,  4,  1,  0,  1],
       [25, 16,  9,  4,  1,  0]])

In [27]:
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, so short! I have a hard time understanding how the algorithm manages to assign the right color to the individual point after averaging the distances between each point and all the other points. That is, I don't understand how, in one line of code that is 'plt.scatter...' it assigns the darkest color to the point that has the smallest average distance between all other points, etc... It must be a new function of matplotlib because the previous version I was using (2.2.5) gave me error.

Comment: @Matteo Please note that `plt.scatter` knows the mean distances, and knows that it must colormap according to the mean distances, because we used the keyword argument `c=m_d` — and doesn't know it by magic… Also, Matplotlib's scatter plots work like this from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses the `pairwise_distances` function in `sklearn`. You might need to install `sklearn` using `pip install scikit-learn`.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
y = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
xy_set1 = np.column_stack([x, y])

x = np.linspace(1.0,15.0,num=100)
y = 2.5*x-8
xy_set2 = np.column_stack([x, y])


#Calculate distances on union of all points
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

all_data = np.row_stack([xy_set1, xy_set2])
distances_matrix = pairwise_distances(all_data)
average_distances = distances_matrix.mean(axis=1)

#Pull out the set1 and set2 parts
average_distances_set1 = average_distances[:len(xy_set1)]
average_distances_set2 = average_distances[len(xy_set1):]

#Plot points and colour by distance (use a reversed colour map)
plt.scatter(xy_set1[:, 0], xy_set1[:, 1], c=average_distances_set1,
            s=100, marker='s', cmap='Reds_r', edgecolors='black',
            label='set 1')

plt.scatter(xy_set2[:, 0], xy_set2[:, 1], c=average_distances_set2,
            s=50, marker='o', zorder=-1, cmap='Reds_r', label='set 2')

#Add colourbar that captures range of all distances
plt.scatter([None] * len(average_distances),
            [None] * len(average_distances),
            c=average_distances, cmap='Reds_r')
plt.colorbar(label='average distance')

plt.legend()
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 3)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

---

An alternative histogram-based approach. It will require more code to map the density visualisation back onto the original points.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
 
x = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
y = np.array([1,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,13,14,15])
xy_set1 = np.column_stack([x, y])

x = np.linspace(1.0,15.0,num=100)
y = 2.5*x-8
xy_set2 = np.column_stack([x, y])

all_data = np.row_stack([xy_set1, xy_set2])
counts, x_bins, y_bins = np.histogram2d(x=all_data[:, 1], y=all_data[:, 0], bins=10)
counts[counts == 0] = np.nan
plt.pcolormesh(x_bins, y_bins, counts, cmap='Reds_r')
plt.colorbar(label='counts')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, it is very near to my goal, but if I have a set of points very dense the solution assigns the same bright color to points that are very dense and very sparse. I'd like the algorithm was able to compare distance among all points, not only points of a specific set (set1 and 2 of example). I show better what I mean in my original post.

Comment: You're welcome. That sounds like a 2D histogram...you want the colour to represent density? I've updated the end of my answer to show a histogram-based approach.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post. I am also interested in your solution, I would like to know if I can use the `pairwise_distances` function for a single set of points, which could be the union vector of set1 and set2. The histogram approach is not familiar for me, so I would discard it for now (and then I like the round better than the square).

Comment: No worries. I have updated my answer to show how you can run `pairwise_distances` over the union of points. The code first stacks the points together, calculates `pairwise_distances`, and then splits it back into colours for set1 and colours for set2.